# Open a file and removing first word in java

Tags: java

My program should be able to read the Zuess file

Look at me!
Look at me!
Look at me NOW!
It is fun to have fun
But you have
to know how.

and write a new file while removing the first word in each line. When I run the program it removes the first word.

```
Courier;} 





\cf0 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0 
at me!\ 
at me!\ 
at me NOW!\ 
is fun to have fun\ 
you have\ 
know how.\
```

that is what it writes, at the end when I try to print out what is in the file I get NewFile.txt only not what is actually in the file can someone please help.

```
//Program that removes the first word from every line in a file

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    //Main Method
    public static void main (String args[]) 
    {

        //Get the system defined
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        //Name of original file
        String origFileName = "zuess.RTF";

        //Name of new file
        String newFileName = "NewFile.txt";

        //Creating the PrintWriter 
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = new PrintWriter
                    (new File(newFileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file " + origFileName);
            System.exit(0);
        }


        //Create scanner
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner
                    (new File(origFileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file " + origFileName);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //While there's lines in the the file
        while(inputStream.hasNextLine())

        {
            //get line in original file
            String line = inputStream.nextLine();
            //split line to get words
            String[] arr = line.split(" ");
            for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                //So the data will print in the new file
                outputStream.write(arr[i] + " ");
            }
            //Line separator
            outputStream.write(newLine);
        }
        //Close Stream
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();


        //catch exception
        try 
        {
            inputStream = new Scanner( new File (newFileName));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file " + newFileName);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("The file " + newFileName + " Contains the following lines: ");
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine())
        {
            String text = inputStream.nextLine();
            System.out.println(newFileName);
        }
        inputStream.close();
    }//End main
}//end class
```

Comment: I want it to just write :
 at me!
 at me!
at me NOW!
 is fun to have fun
 you have
 know how.

Comment: Look at me!
Look at me!
Look at me NOW!
It is fun to have fun
But you have
to know how.

Comment: that is what the original file says.

Comment: please edit your question with the properly formatted input file and what you want it to be.

Comment: Is that better formatted?

Comment: Yep very nice. ill read through it

Comment: Okay so your problem is that you are using .rtf format... just use .txt

Comment: Made the change on the file and it is still giving me the same problem.

Comment: Okay i posted an answer it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {

    //Get the system defined
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    //Name of original file
    String origFileName = "new.txt";

    //Name of new file
    String newFileName = "NewFile.txt";

    //Creating the PrintWriter
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = new PrintWriter
                (new File(newFileName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        System.out.println("Error opening the file " + origFileName);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //Opening origin file and getting all lines
    Path pathA = Paths.get(origFileName);
    List<String> file = Files.readAllLines(pathA);

    //for every line from origin file
    for ( String line: file) {

        //split line to get words
        String[] arr = line.split(" ");
        for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            //So the data will print in the new file
            outputStream.write(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        //Line separator
        outputStream.write(newLine);
    }
    //Close Stream
    outputStream.close();

}
```

Comment: It is still writing the file the same way sadly or is that just how the file is always going to get written.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go try this: It is using the version "zuess.txt" not "zuess.rtf"

```
package test;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    //Main Method
    public static void main (String args[]) 
    {
        String origFileName = "zuess.txt";
        String newFileName = "NewFile.txt";

        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = new PrintWriter
                    (new File(newFileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file " + origFileName);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner
                    (new File(origFileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file " + origFileName);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        while(inputStream.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = inputStream.nextLine();
            String[] arr = line.split(" ");
            for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
                outputStream.write(arr[i]+" ");
            outputStream.println();
        }
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        try 
        {
            inputStream = new Scanner( new File (newFileName));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file " + newFileName);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println("The file " + newFileName + " Contains the following lines: ");
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine())
        {
            String text = inputStream.nextLine();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
        inputStream.close();
    }//End main
}//end class
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is the file always going to be written in that format? The things in the " " and the \?

"Courier;} "  





"\cf0 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0 "  
at me!\   
at me!\   
at me NOW!\   
is fun to have fun\   
you have\   
know how.\

Comment: What do you mean.? Well with the simple lines of text you gave me i just simply made a txt file containing those.

Comment: In the new file it is always writing  Courier; } and \cf0  \expnd0 \expndtw0 \kerning0